# Error in transposing CoffeeScript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have used CoffeeScript for about three months to build a web application recently. I had an error in the transposed JavaScript code and the strange thing is that this part of code has an error doesn't match any code in the CoffeeScript and I totally don't know what this code means and and why it's giving me that error.

The error is:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

on the first line of this part code:

```
var bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
extend = function(child, parent) { 
    for (var key in parent) { 
        if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) 
            child[key] = parent[key]; 
    } function ctor() { 
        this.constructor = child; 
    } 
    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; 
    child.prototype = new ctor(); 
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype; 
    return child; 
},
hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;
```

Can anyone tell me why I am having this part of code in the transposed JavaScript and why it gives that error ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the code immediately before that code.

Comment: 'VIBE.Collections.CameraItems = (function(superClass) {
  extend(CameraItems, superClass);

  function CameraItems() {
    return CameraItems.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  CameraItems.prototype.url = function() {
    return server('/cams.json');
  };

  CameraItems.prototype.model = VIBE.Models.CameraItem;

  return CameraItems;

})(Backbone.Collection);'

Comment: thought it may have been trailing garbage there, but no

Comment: okay, Thank you anyway :)

Comment: `bind` is used to implement `=>` inside classes, `extend` is used to implement the `extends` keyword, `hasProp` is used to implement the `own` part of `for own k of obj` and in inheritance; the presence of that code just means that you have a `class A extends B` and an `=>` method in your CoffeeScript. Your problem lies elsewhere, can you provide an example of the CoffeeScript that is causing this problem?

Comment: Thank you @muistooshort , it was an indentation error and I solved it